# SQL - Calculating time of a step without a end of execution

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve a problem and would like someone to help me.

I have the following table:

```
Cod Name    Date
--- ------- -----------------------
  1 Test_01 2019-10-30 11:19:45.020
  2 Test_02 2019-10-30 10:19:13.887
  3 Test_03 2019-10-30 10:10:34.120
  4 Test_04 2019-10-30 10:09:20.650
```

I only have the start date of the execution in a column. Therefore, the end of the execution of Test_04 is the beginning of Test_03, the same in Test_02.

I have to make a query that calculates the time between the beginning and the end of execution of each row, but I am not able to because I do not have the column with the end of execution.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What about the *End Time* of Test_04 / last test? You would never know! Do you have the "power" to change the process that run the test to save the end time as well?

Comment: What `sql` engine are you using? MySQL / MSSQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what's your database, so I'll assume it's PostgreSQL.

You can use the `LEAD()`  function as in:

```
select t.*,
  lead(start) over(order by start) - start as duration
from t
```

Result:

```
| cod | name    | start                    | duration                            |
| --- | ------- | ------------------------ | ----------------------------------- |
| 4   | Test_04 | 2019-10-30T10:09:20.650Z | {"minutes":1,"seconds":13,"ms":470} |
| 3   | Test_03 | 2019-10-30T10:10:34.120Z | {"minutes":8,"seconds":39,"ms":767} |
| 2   | Test_02 | 2019-10-30T10:19:13.887Z | {"hours":1,"seconds":31,"ms":133}   |
| 1   | Test_01 | 2019-10-30T11:19:45.020Z | null                                |
```

See [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eCNmtrjuJVjwCCBdnVCCJU/0).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `lead()`:

```
select t.*, lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
from t;
```

You can calculate the duration using the appropriate date/time functions for your database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your **DBMS** so I'm answering in T-SQL.
The problem here is purely how to correlate two consecutive rows.
If `Cod` is a perfect sequence it's very easy. If not this answer is *invalid* as it requires a better way to correlate then.
The `DATEDIFF` part is entirely DBMS flavored.

```
create table dbo.Test
(
  Cod int not null,
  Name varchar(100) not null,
  Date datetime not null
)
GO

insert into dbo.Test
(Cod, Name, Date) values
(1, 'Test_01', '2019-10-30 11:19:45.020'),
(2, 'Test_02', '2019-10-30 10:19:13.887'),
(3, 'Test_03', '2019-10-30 10:10:34.120'),
(4, 'Test_04', '2019-10-30 10:09:20.650')
GO

select t0.Name, DATEDIFF(second, t1.Date, t0.Date) as period
from dbo.Test t0
join dbo.Test t1 on t1.Cod = t0.Cod+1
GO


Name       period (in seconds)
----------- -----------
Test_01    3632
Test_02    519
Test_03    74

(3 row(s) affected)
```